# How can I add animation of GASP as background in React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, gsap

For ex: this is a simple animation effect. How can I use it in my React application.

```
https://codepen.io/celli/pen/xZgpvN
```

```html
<div id="container" />

<!-- React -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<!-- TweenMax -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.15.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
```

**Is there any other example or demos to embed animation as background in my React webapp.**

P.S. Looking with the latest class based React app.

Comment: I think you forgot to add the code. Try adding the code in codesandbox.io and share the link of your problem.
This question is incomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see at least two possibilities to achieve that:

1. When developing a React application, there is still a regular webpage around it. React gets loaded into an element inside the webpage. You could, for example, have the background effect in another `div` than the React application.
2. If you want to have use it inside the React app (for example as background of a single component), you could use a `<div ref={backgroundAnimationRef} />` and set the effect up in either a `useEffect` hook or in class based `componentDidMount`. You might need to add a cleanup function depending on your effect in `componentWillUnmount` or the return value of `useEffect`.

If you need the effect everywhere on the page, I'd go with option 1. If you need more flexibility (have it multiple times on the page / on different sections in your app or its width/height is dependent on some React component), I'd choose option 2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please share some demo code. Also I have a doubt regarding destructuring my code. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63000709/how-do-i-integrate-a-js-animation-code-in-react-application

Comment: You have working demo code in the answer that you link to...? I don't understand what you need